# EJB transactions are being committed after flush in Glassfish

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish, multi-tenant, c3p0

EDIT: When I turn on Glassfish's transaction logging:

```
CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl --Created new JavaEETransactionImpl, txId = 21 
Hibernate: update ... 
Hibernate: delete ... 
CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl  --In JavaEETransactionImpl.commit, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null
```

`JavaEETransactionImpl` commits correctly after both sql statements are run.

**I also checked the instance of C3P0 Connection during the transaction (after the update and before the delete) and the `Connection.getAutoCommit()` returns `true`!** Which is the reason, why the sql statements are committed, when calling `getEntityManager().flush()`.

AFAIK the Connection should not be in the autoCommit mode during the transaction and it is Hibernate's responsibility to turn it off. When I turn the autoCommit off, when creating a Connection instance in `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`, changes are never committed.

So the problem is, that **Hibernate is not turning off the connection's autoCommit and also is not calling `connection.commit()` after the transaction.** (commits are only performed, because of default autoCommit set to true in C3P0). **Why?**

---

Having the following setup:

Glassfish 4.0, Hibernate 5.0.7 set up for [multi-tenancy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) using database approach, C3P0 serving connections for Hibernate via `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` implementation and MS SQL Server 2014,

transactions in **container managed** beans are not working.

**For instance**, I have a business method in stateless session bean, that deletes an entity:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void remove(IPersistentObject entity, IUser user) {
    entity.setModifiedBy(user.getIdentification());
    entity.setModifiedDate(ZonedDateTime.now());
    entity.setStatus(DataRecordStatus.DELETED);

    IPersistentObject merge = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    getEntityManager().flush();

    getEntityManager().remove(merge);
    getEntityManager().flush();

}
```

In the first step, this method sets the entity metadata about who and when performed the delete. After that, flush() is called in order to trigger the database update trigger, which saves the changes into history table. After that, the entity is removed from the live (non-history) table.

**Problem is**, that this is not performed in one transaction. When I debug the code, right after the first flush, I can see the DELETED Status in the database, although the transaction should still be running and being committed only after the end of the EJB method.

When I execute this method for an entity, that cannot be deleted, because it is referenced in another table, `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown, but the metadata changes are not rolled back and the entity remains in corrupted state (DELETED Status).

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="sqlServerTestPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <!-- We are multi tenant, do not specify JTA data source     
    <jta-data-source>${db.jdbcName}</jta-data-source> -->
    <!-- 3 -->
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.showSql}"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="${hibernate.showSql}"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
      <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="at.ts.wh.dal.WHMultiTenantConnectionProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="at.ts.wh.dal.WHCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I log retrieving/releasing connections from `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` I get something like this:

```
TENANT1 getConnection com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@73b9aad9]]
Hibernate: update ...
Hibernate: delete ...
TENANT1 releaseConnection com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@73b9aad9]]
```

Which looks like the connection is held for the whole business method (transaction), which is OK, but the commit is made already by flushing.

How can I make the transactions working? Thanks for your help!

Comment: FWIW You should be able to see changes if the transaction isolation is READ UNCOMMITTED. Is it?

Comment: Transaction isolation level is READ COMMITED.

Comment: so look in the JPA providers log. I'd expect them to log basic stuff like tx.commit

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it as soon as I can.

Comment: @NeilStockton I have simply turned on all hibernate logs (log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ALL), but there was no info of tx.start or tx.commit. So I turned on Glassfish transaction logs, which is highly verbose, but I read there:
[CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl] [METHODNAME: <init>] [[
  --Created new JavaEETransactionImpl, txId = 21]]
Hibernate: update ...
Hibernate: delete ...
[CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl] [METHODNAME: commit] [[
  --In JavaEETransactionImpl.commit, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null]]

which looks ok

Comment: @NeilStockton please look at my edited original post. Thanks!